# Edit Downloaded JSON file (React)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a button on my webpage, that downloads a JSON file.
I want to modify this JSON file to have a few more characters at the beginning and at the end.

How is it possible?
This is the code I wrote:

```
const downloadJSON = (json) => {
 const begin = `beginning: `;
  const end = `\nTheEnd`;
  const jsonStringFile = `data:text/json;chatset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
    JSON.stringify(json),
  )}`;
  const jsonString = begin + jsonStringFile + end; // what I tried
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = jsonString;
  link.download = 'correctionSummary.json';

  link.click();
};
```

Comment: What you're creating is invalid JSON.

Comment: So how can I edit its contents?

Comment: All you're doing is adding strings to the beginning and end of the JSON string. That doesn't make valid JSON. If you want to edit the keys/values of the JSON [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) into a JS strucuture (array/object), make your updates, and then stringify that structure back to JSON.